# Why won't a new 64-bit Windows 7 laptop start a setup.exe file?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I'm helping someone set up their new **64-bit Acer Aspire One Netbook** and have set everything up perfectly except the **HP OfficeJet 4500 Wireless printer**. The problem is I can't get the setup.exe file to work:

- put install CD in, double-clicked on setup.exe, nothing happened
- copied CD contents to hard drive, double-clicked on setup.exe, nothing happened
- downloaded newest driver from HP website, double-clicked setup.exe, nothing happened
- did right-click, run as administrator, nothing happened
- (put CD in another computer (32-bit Windows XP), double-clicked on setup.exe, worked fine)
- (other setup.exe files work fine)

**How can I get this setup.exe file to execute on this computer?**

Comment: Do other .exe's open ok?

Comment: It sounds like your trying to run a 32-bit installer on a 64-bit operating system.  Of course you also might have malware if your unable to launch any installer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Download the appropriate W7 64bit driver from here,](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/pfinder?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&tool=&query=office%20jet%204500#N29) see it it will execute and install.

Comment: I never use the CDs that come with products.  It's choke full of crapware. Or even better, full of malware ala Sony.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to execute as compatibility mode.
Right click on setup.exe and select "Properties", then "Compatibility", mark "Execute this program in compatibility mode", then you could select for example "Windows XP SP1".

Take a try and post your results, if it dont works, try another compatibility, as Windows Vista for example, I hope one of them will going to works.

Answer (score 1):

32 bit installers often still contain a 16 bit launcher application for compatibility. On a 32 bit system this is no problem as it emulates the 16 bit system. 
But on 64 bit systems like yours only 32 bit software can be run - 16 bit software does not work anymore.

I assume that you discovered an installer that still uses such a 16 bit launcher and hence this setup can not be run on your computer.